Calculate distances from points to nearest edges of polygons
I have this list of lat/long coordinates (from Google maps).
tpts <- data.frame(lat = c(40.91947468397188, 39.13618031492076,
                           44.54912813480803, 38.55433576050368,
                           36.833190022953396, 41.111132432433234), 
                   lon = c(-2.341558113881383, -6.780034564585769,
                           -7.219487678516898, 2.602289417843798,
                           -10.339604787427902, -4.234324))

I also have this spatVector of polygons (example data provided with tidyterra R package)
extfile <- system.file("extdata/cyl.gpkg", package = "tidyterra")
cyl <- terra::vect(extfile)

I want to calculate the distance from each point in tpts to the nearest edge of each polygon in cyl.
Here is what I did, but I am not certain if this approach is correct (related - I tried to add lonlat = TRUE to terra::distance() and I get error that lonlat was unused.  Same for haversine option.  I was trying to see how these options changed the returned distance matrix). It was not clear to me from manpage if this below approach (with distance()) is calculating to the nearest polygon edge or to the centroid or something else of each polygon.  I put a point in center of each polygon and ran distance() again and got different results, so it seems to not be distance to polygon centroids, but I'd like to confirm it is indeed distance to the nearest edge.
#make pts into a spatvect so distance() will accept them
pts.sv <- terra::vect(tpts, geom = c("lon","lat"), crs = crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
#put into same crs as polygons (not sure if I need to do this?)
pts.sv <- terra::project(pts.sv, crs(cyl))

#looks right
ggplot() + geom_spatvector(data = cyl) +
  geom_spatvector(data = pts.sv)

#calc distances from each point to nearest edge of each polygon
terra::distance(pts.sv, cyl, unit = "m")


Using your point to polygon distance example, terra::distance() calculates the distance from each point in pts.sv to the nearest edge of each polygon in cyl. It does not calculate the distance to the polygon centroids. Also, your assumption is correct, both data need to have the same CRS.
To illustrate this further, let's compare the results from terra::distance() and the equivalent sf::st_distance(). Both do the same thing.
library(terra)

# Sample coordinate df
tpts <- data.frame(lat = c(40.91947468397188, 39.13618031492076,
                           44.54912813480803, 38.55433576050368,
                           36.833190022953396, 41.111132432433234), 
                   lon = c(-2.341558113881383, -6.780034564585769,
                           -7.219487678516898, 2.602289417843798,
                           -10.339604787427902, -4.234324))

# Load sample system data and convert to SpatVector
extfile <- system.file("extdata/cyl.gpkg", package = "tidyterra")
cyl <- terra::vect(extfile)

# Create SpatVector from pts
pts.sv <- vect(tpts, geom = c("lon","lat"), 
               crs = crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Project pts.sv to same CRS as cyl
pts.sv <- project(pts.sv, crs(cyl))

# Calculate nearest edge distance from each point to each polygon
terra_dist <- as.numeric(distance(pts.sv, cyl, unit = "m"))

Now, the sf version:
library(sf)

# Create sf equivalent objects
cyl_sf <- st_as_sf(cyl)
pts_sf <- st_as_sf(pts.sv)

# Calculate nearest edge distance from each point to each polygon
sf_dist <- as.numeric(st_distance(pts_sf, cyl_sf))

Finally, compare the results:
all.equal(terra_dist, sf_dist)
# [1] TRUE

As you can see, both produce identical results. Admittedly, the documentation is sparse but you are getting the result you want.
If you want to confirm, check out my answer here that shows the workflow for generating lines between points to the nearest edge of another feature. In that example, it's point-to-lines, but the principle is the same.
